# Apache mod-auth-mysql with phpass encrypted password (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, basic-authentication, apache-modules, phpass

I need to have password protection on some web pages outside of the main Wordpress site. The users would prefer to use the usernames and passwords they already have in the Wordpress.

The obvious solution would seem to be to use the Apace module for Mysql based authentication: mod-auth-mysql.

This however does not seem to be possible, because Wordpress uses Phpass password encryption, which is not supported by mod-auth-mysql.

- http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/CONFIGURE
- http://www.openwall.com/phpass/
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32004/how-to-validate-wordpress-generated-password-in-db-using-php

Is there any way to get around this limitation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a patched version of mod-auth-mysql to accept Phpass encrypted passwords. I'll include instructions on how to do this in ubuntu and debian.

[The raw patch file is available here](https://pelam.fi/published_sources/mod-auth-mysql-phpass/patch.diff)

### Patching Mod-auth-mysql in Ubuntu/Debian to support Phpass

These instructions have been tested in Ubuntu 10.4, 12.04 and 14.04.5, but should work on many other Debian based platforms with minimal changes.

Create a working directory for building the patched .deb package

```
mkdir mod-auth-mysql-phpass
cd mod-auth-mysql-phpass
```

Get dependencies needed for building the package and the package source.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mod-auth-mysql fakeroot
apt-get source mod-auth-mysql
```

Go to the newly created source folder.

```
cd mod-auth-mysql-4.3.9
```

Use Debian tool to create a properly debian formatted patch (.dpatch). First check the current list of patches.

```
cat debian/patches/00list
```

The last official patch will be at the end of the list. Use the name of the last patch
as the last argument of dpatch-edit-patch command below. Also pick a number one greater for the name of the new phpass patch.
In my case the last patch in the list was 017-doc_persistent_conn.dpatch and the name of phpass patch is then 018-phpass.

```
dpatch-edit-patch patch 018-phpass 017-doc_persistent_conn.dpatch
```

dpatch-edit-patch will start a new shell inside a special folder that
it will use to build the custom debian formatted patch.

download the raw patch

```
wget https://pelam.fi/published_sources/mod-auth-mysql-phpass/patch.diff
```

Apply the raw patch and delete it.

```
patch < patch.diff
rm patch.diff
```

Tell dpatch-edit-patch that our custom patch can be generated.

```
exit
```

Wonder at your new properly Debian formatted patch. You should also
review the changes made by this unofficial patch if you care about security :)

```
cat debian/patches/018-phpass.dpatch
```

Add the new patch to the list of patches to be applied when .deb package is built.

```
echo 018-phpass.dpatch >> debian/patches/00list
```

Build the patched package

```
dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc
```

Now you can install your custom built .deb package (the built package name may vary depending on your system).

```
sudo dpkg --install ../libapache2-mod-auth-mysql_4.3.9-13.1ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

### Configuring Mod-auth-mysql to Authenticate Against Wordpress Using Phpass

Enable mod-auth-mysql:

```
sudo a2enmod auth_mysql
```

Restart apache for the new module to take effect:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The documentation (Now including Phpass) can be viewed with eg. less command

```
zless /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-auth-mysql/DIRECTIVES.gz
```

Here is a sample .htaccess file that allows access only for Wordpress administrators:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Give Wordpress Administrator username and password"

Auth_MySQL_User YOUR_MYSQL_USER_HERE
Auth_MySQL_Password YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD_HERE
Auth_MySQL_Host YOUR_MYSQL_SERVER_HERE

AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
# I don't know a better way to disable the default password file authentication
AuthUserFile /dev/null
Auth_MySQL on
Auth_MySQL_DB YOUR_WORDPRESS_MYSQL_SCHEMA_NAME_HERE
Auth_MySQL_Password_Table wp_users
Auth_MySQL_Username_Field wp_users.user_login
Auth_MySQL_Password_Field wp_users.user_pass
Auth_MySQL_Encryption_Types PHPass PHP_MD5

Auth_MySQL_Group_Table "wp_users, wp_usermeta"
Auth_MySQL_Group_Clause "AND wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id AND wp_usermeta.meta_key='wp-capabilities' and m.meta_value like '%s:13:\"administrator\"%'"
Auth_MySQL_Persistent On
Auth_MySQL_Authoritative Off
Auth_MySQL_CharacterSet utf8

Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: First off, this is excellent. The patch works great and compiled. I see nothing nefarious in the code. :) However, it never seems to authenticate against the PHPBB3 database. I am running 3.09 on Ubuntu 12.04 with MySQL and Apache2 and nothing in the logs or anything. I have no way to debug and nothing I try seems to make this work. My configuration is almost identical to the one above except the Group stuff is left out. Any ideas? Was this tested against PHPBB3?

Comment: Thanks to mhradek for pointing out that PHPBB3 escapes HTML special characters in the password as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13240528/1148030. The old version of the patch is available at http://pelam.fi/published_sources/mod-auth-mysql-phpass/patch-pre-phpbb3-support.diff The patch http://pelam.fi/published_sources/mod-auth-mysql-phpass/patch.diff referred to in above answer has been updated to handle escaping when PHPBB3 variant of PHPASS is detected.